# ReactJS: Accessing object inside state and updating it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My state object looks something like this:

```
getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            people: [
            {'id': 1, 'first': "Jake", 'last': "A", 'title': "Associate", 'company': "Twitter", 'stage': "Onsite"},
            {'id': 2, 'first': "Graham", 'last': "R", 'title': "Eng", 'company': "GitHub", 'stage': "Recruiter"}
            ],
        }
    },
```

If I wanted to access Jake's record and change company name, how would I specifically chose him?

```
updateCandidate: function() {
    this.setState({
       ....how do I pick Jake's company and change it to Google?
    )}
)
```

Quick update:

1.) added id's to state

2.) This helper function:

```
var RenderPeople = React.createClass({
    change: function(e) {
        var id = this.props.user.id
        var user = this.props.user
        this.props.updateCandidate(id, user, e.target.value)
    },

var Dashboard = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            people: [
            {'id': 1, 'first': "Jake", 'last': "A", 'title': "Associate", 'company': "Twitter", 'stage': "Onsite"},
            {'id': 2, 'first': "Graham", 'last': "R", 'title': "Eng", 'company': "GitHub", 'stage': "Recruiter"}
            ],
        }
    },

    updateCandidate:function(id, user, newStage){
        this.state.people.map(val => {
            if(val['id'] === id){
                console.log(val); // this works!
                console.log(newStage); //this works!
                this.setState({
                    [val['stage']] : newStage
                }, function() {'this ran'});
            }
        })
    },
```

For some reason `this.setState` isn't running. Any reason why?

Answer (score 4):

Map through the people array, when you find an element whose `first` value equals Jake, use Spread Syntax (`{ ...}`) to return the amended object.

```
const newPeople = people.map(val => {
  if(val['first'] === "Jake"){
    return { ...val, val['company']: 'Google'};
  }
});

//EDIT:
// call setState after the call to map is complete:
this.setState({people: newPeople}):
```

Comment: tip: you don't need to add the `this` to the `map()` call when using `=>` for the anon function :)

Comment: @MatthewHerbst: Thanks.  It's a force of habit from the need to do so within ES6 class syntax :)

Comment: I wonder the performance difference between spreading versus using `Object.assign({}, val, { company: 'Google' })`

Comment: Or even just explicitly doing `val.company = 'Google'; return val;`

Comment: Isn't the spread just sugar that transpiles to `Object.assign` (if using a transpiler of course)

Comment: And I guess explicitly setting the value shouldn't hurt given changes  in `.map` don't mutate the state.

Comment: Hey @pineda thanks for the suggestion. I updated the code. Can you see anything that I'm doing wrong? for some reason setState() isn't running.

Comment: I wouldn't run the setState in a loop.  Run it _after_ the loop has been completed.

Comment: how would I change the right row inside people then?

Comment: doesn't your example add another row to people vs mutating one inside it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130990/discussion-between-pineda-and-morgan-allen).